# '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'

Tags: react-native, kotlin, kotlin-experimental

e: /Users/abc/update/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/TaskConfiguration.kt: (29, 33): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'[image]

i want to build the native project

Comment: I installed an older version of react-native-gradle-plugin to fix it for me

Comment: @Anthony - what version?

Answer (score 10):

`@steformicola` answer didn't work for me but changing the gradle version in

> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip`

worked for me.

Look at [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34410) for related issues.

Comment: I am already using 7.5.1

Answer (score 6):

Just upgraded to Gradle 7.5.1 and it works. Inside your android directory run:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5.1 --distribution-type=all
```

Comment: This command returns the same error for me

Comment: Do you have any fix for that?