# react-native-gradle-plugin kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-experimental

I have been trying to build React Native App i have been searching everywhere I cannot solve this issue. Any help or advise would be very much apprenticed.

My Android build has this error:

```
/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/tasks/BundleHermesCTask.kt: (137, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'
```

In the react-native-gradle-plugin i have found the file BundleHermesCTask.kt. Within this file it is showing me an error at this function i can put this line above the function @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class) and the program will build and work but changing the node module is not a solution as it will be overwritten.

```
 internal fun getBundleCommand(bundleFile: File, sourceMapFile: File): List<Any> =
  windowsAwareCommandLine(
      buildList {
        addAll(nodeExecutableAndArgs.get())
        add(cliFile.get().asFile.absolutePath)
        add(bundleCommand.get())
        add("--platform")
        add("android")
        add("--dev")
        add(devEnabled.get().toString())
        add("--reset-cache")
        add("--entry-file")
        add(entryFile.get().asFile.toString())
        add("--bundle-output")
        add(bundleFile.toString())
        add("--assets-dest")
        add(resourcesDir.get().asFile.toString())
        add("--sourcemap-output")
        add(sourceMapFile.toString())
        if (bundleConfig.isPresent) {
          add("--config")
          add(bundleConfig.get().asFile.absolutePath)
        }
        add("--minify")
        add(minifyEnabled.get().toString())
        addAll(extraPackagerArgs.get())
        add("--verbose")
      })
```

I have search online and tried everything from checking my java version and checking all dependencies are loading the same version also updating react native and dependencies. the only thing i can get to work is changing the file BundleHermesCTask.kt and i cannot do this as the build process will move the app and do npm install of all dependencies and the changes are lost.

I have checked the github pages and also been trying to figure out kotlin more about kotlin and reading the docs on the
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements

Answer (score 1):

What version of Gradle are your using? I solved by upgrading to Gradle 7.5.1 as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74544868/9310129)

Comment: This did not work for me. It only worked in the debug build once i went to do a release build it didn't work. (App Crash in Release Build. FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context) I had to use Gradle to 7.3.3 then down grade react-native-gradle-plugin@0.70.3